# Backbone.js How to iterate collection in descending order

Tags: backbone.js

I have a collection and I want to loop through it but starting from the last index to the first. Is it possible? How?

Comment: Try `_.each(collection.last(collection.length).reverse(), function(model){ });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
bc.chain().reverse().each(function(item){console.log(item)});
```

That will 'chain' the collection, reverse it and iterated over the reversed version.

Hope that helps.